# For a MVC application, update values of multiple columns every 3 months in database and send e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

For a MVC application I am developing, I need to update the values of certain columns of a table in database every quarter i.e. on 1st day of Jan, Apr, July and Oct every year.

For example, if the table currently looks something like:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| EmpId | Experience_Prior | Qualification | Specialization |        Status        | LastSubmitted |  NextDue   | ApprovedOn |
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| EmpId | 0.00             | B.Tech        | CSE            | Assessment Submitted | 2016-11-20    | 2017-01-01 | 2016-11-20 |
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Then on the 1st day of next quarter, the columns Status, LastSubmitted, NextDue and ApprovedOn have to be updated as:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| EmpId | Experience_Prior | Qualification | Specialization |       Status       | LastSubmitted |  NextDue   | ApprovedOn |
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| EmpId | 0.00             | B.Tech        | CSE            | Assessment Overdue | NULL          | 2017-01-04 | NULL       |
+-------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

In case it's unclear, NextDue should be updated to the 1st day of next quarter.
This has to be followed by an email to all users using the application.

I know how to update the columns and send emails from the application. I just need to know how to execute all these every quarter.

The application is an intranet MVC4 application and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: this is more appropriate for a job or service rather than a web application.

Comment: http://hangfire.io/ can do the job.

Comment: another vote for hangfire

Comment: I'll look into hangfire

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, Use Background job to update it ex([HangFire](http://hangfire.io/)), But you will have another challenge that you can't use system.net and smtp to send emails as there is no HttpRequest, you will have to use service for sending ex ([mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)) or may be there is a workaround for that !!.

second option, Create a static variables contains last modified dates (or table in db) and check it with Current date everytime you will update, If Ok do your update, send emails, update last modified date again.

Hope that help

Comment: In the second option, by  'every time you will update' you mean every time the tables are updated right.

Comment: If that is so, then that is  what I am doing right now. But, the user is required to access the application only once in a quarter. So, there is no guarantee when they are going to update.

Comment: @ShyProgrammer That's why you will save last modified date and you will compare it with now date, If Ok -> Update, else-> not update

Answer (score -1):

Use cronjob or Quartz scheduler that will Schedule and trigger on 1st date of every Quarter to run your Java Program/Application and update the Database columns.

Comment: This is not a Java application